# Polymorphic association fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, polymorphic-associations, rails-activerecord, has-one

In my rails 3.2 application I have a User model and a Physician model with the following polymorphic associations:

**User**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :authenticatable_id, :authenticatable_type, :email
  belongs_to :authenticatable, polymorphic: true
end
```

**Physician**

```
class Physician < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name
  has_one :user, as: :authenticatable
end
```

I wanted to test these out in the console and encountered a strange thing. Doing:

```
p = Physician.new
p.user.build
```

gives me `NoMethodError: undefined method 'build' for nil:NilClass` - but why would the physician's user attribute be `nil`?

Strangely, when I change the physician model to `has_many :users` instead of `has_one :user` and do

```
p = Physician.new
p.users.build
```

everything works fine.

What am I missing to get the `has_one` association to work?

Comment: You probably should do `p.build_user` since has_one doesn't add .build method

Comment: @VadimChumel Awesome, that's exactly what I needed! Please add this as an answer so I can accept and upvote it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably should do `p.build_user` since `has_one` doesn't add `association.build` method. You can also check apidock about methods [has_one](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_one) and [has_many](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods/has_many) 'injects' into your model.

Answer (score 0):

It is not entirely clear to me, but it seems that your are creating a `Physician` that is also a `User`. So it is able to make use of the features a `User` provides.

Your implementation creates two objects one `Physician` and one`User`, but when strictly looking at the situation, both are the same Physician/User.

So you should let `Physician` inherit from `User`:

```
class Physician < User
```

and remove the polymorphic relation between `Physician` and `User`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I am using Devise's user model and simply need different user roles. For example, there is not only a physician, but later there might also be a pharmacy, etc - but they are all users. So I think the polymorphic association is the right approach, I just need to get the association working... Any ideas?

Comment: The roles can implemented using the inheritance. For example `class Pharmacy < User` is also valid. Unless you will get users with multiple roles at the same time...